# LIMIT EM UMA QUERY EM UM CAMPO

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela onde existem dois campos com valores possíveis: sim-não. O select que estou fazendo é esse:

```
select 
      nome, 
      media, 
      escola as 'Particular', 
      bairro as 'COTA DE BAIRRO' 

from 
      alunos 
where 
      curso = 'Enfermagem' 

order by 
      media desc, nome asc, 
      (CASE WHEN bairro = 'Sim' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
      (CASE WHEN escola = 'Sim' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Queria que no campo Particular, retornasse apenas 8 valores com resultado 'Sim' e no campo bairro 2 valores com resultado 'Sim'. Não da pra fazer com limit, pois o limit retorna o limite de todas as linhas consultadas, e eu queria que limitasse apenas o numero de resultados com Sim de duas colunas

Comment: E se o mesmo registro possuir `escola='sim'` e `bairro='sim'`? Ele deverá contar tanto nos 8 registros de Particular quando nos 2 de Bairro?

Comment: siiim, é que tô fazendo um sistema de pre matrículas, aí queria retornar um ranking, como deu para perceber, e as regras do edital declara que precisa ter 8 alunos de escola particular e 2 alunos com cota de bairro

Comment: Então não faz muito sentido ele ser considerado duas vezes. Se o aluno já entrou por estudar em escola particular, não deveria tomar a vaga de uma cota de bairro, não?

Comment: tem razão, não havia pensado nisso, e de fato, nos editais anteriores o aluno com menores médias eram sempre os com cota de bairro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer a consulta com um union, excluindo os alunos que já estão na cota particular de entrar também na cota de bairro.

```
with
 tb_particular as 
    (select nome, media, 'cota escola particular' as 'tipo_cota'
    from aluno
    where particular=true
    order by media desc
    limit 8)
select * from tb_particular
union
(select nome, media, 'cota bairro' as 'tipo_cota'
    from aluno
    where cota_bairro=true
        and  (nome not in (select nome from tb_particular))
    order by media desc
    limit 2)
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nxsMTvdekLjXjcqBdEzyMj/1)

Observações:

- o 'with' que usei na consulta é recurso do mysql 8.0. Se você não
  estiver usando essa versão teria que fazer um union do primeiro
  select (o atribuído a tb_particular) com o segundo select e repetir
  todo o primeiro select como parametro pro 'not in';
- eu usei a coluna 'nome' no not in, mas no caso real você usaria a primary key da
  tabela.

Comment: isso é exatamente o que eu preciso, porém, não está suportando o with e as instruções do que fazer com union não ficaram muito claras, vc tem como esclarecer melhor, por favor

Comment: Então, vc pode contornar isso sem usar o with, repetindo o primeiro select dentro dos parênteses `not in(...)`. Talvez tenha outra maneira, não uso mysql. Segunda posso dar uma olhada. Não entendi a dúvida sobre o union.

Comment: eu falei errado, desculpa. Você falou que caso não suportasse o with (não o suporta) eu tinha que fazer outra instrução para substitui-lo, essa instrução que não ficou clara pra mim.

Comment: O mesmo select que vc usou para selecionar os alunos de cota por escola particular, você tem que usar no select de alunos de cota de bairro, para que eles não seja incluídos neste último. Com o with você evita isso. Sem o with você pode fazer assim https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9fdKrGHtxfgqMwfh4EWTxk/0

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Você pode utilizar a clausula **LIMIT** {numero de linhas} **ou** utilizar a clausula **TOP** {numero de linhas} **ou** a clausula **ROWNUM** =< {numero de linhas}

**Referência:** [Utilizando as clausulas LIMIT, TOP ou ROWNUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

**2.** Você pode realizar dois select distintos, um para recuperar o bairro e outro para recuperar a escola, porque você quer recuperar um numero diferente de linhas para cada resultado, analisando seu problema, aparentemente os **ORDER BY** podem ser diferentes, uma ótima oportunidade para melhorar ainda mais seu código. Você também pode fazer um **UNION** para trazer os dois resultados (acredito ser a melhor maneira).

**Referência:** [Utilizando UNION](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all/37457)

**3.** Ficaria muito mais performático sua consulta se invés de você utilizar o **CASE** no **ORDER BY**, você utilizar o **CASE** no **SELECT**.

**Referência:** [Utilizando a Clausula CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)